# Storing Serial data from Bluetooth to an Array by filtering and adding delimiters

Tags: java, android, arrays

For an instance I receive 5000 samples of data from a bluetooth device and a sample of data looks like:

```
FA 00 3E 53 45 32 45 2A 3A 3B FB
```

While I read using Bluetooth socket what I get is

```
-FA 
-00 
-3E 
-53 
-45 
-32 
-45 
-2A 
-3A 
-3B
-FB
-FA 
-00 
-3E 
-53 
-45 
-32 
-45 
-2A 
-3A 
-3B
-FB
-.
-.
-.
-.
-.
-.
-.
-.
-FB
```

I need to store this data into array as:

```
String arr[]=[~FA,00,3E,53,45,32,45,2A,3A,3B,FB ~FA,00,3E,53,45,32,45,2A,3A,3B,FB]
```

How to achieve this result?

//Note: These data are real time, and they are continous.

Comment: What have you written as code so far? SO users won't code the answer for you as I am sure you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ArrayList to store data as they come

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

then add all value like this
`list.add("FA")` // this will add string "FA" in list

for reference check this link to understand arraylist https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp